# How to send server validation messages to Angular2 from Java?

Tags: java, angular, hystrix

my application uses Angular2. Suppose if user try to login and if my server need to contact other authenticate server to proceed login.but if that authenticate server is down. so using Hystrix i can cget to knw about that in my server. but how to update or show in my angular2 application these kind of 'server busy' or'try after some time messages in angular2. for same HTTP call for login to server from Angular2.

Comment: my applcation Architecture is  Angular2-->Server-->AuthenticateServer

Comment: you should handle various failure types in the Server call. throw a different exception based on service unavailable, timeouts, etc. handle those failures in the failure callback on the angular side.

Comment: can u give me example code

Comment: in your server when you attempt to make the call to your authentication server, youll typically surround that attempt in a try{}catch(){} block. each catch should handle a different type of failure. for the catch on ServiceUnavailableException you would build your response object with an http failure code and whatever other info youd like. On the angular side, the service call will see the failure status, and call the callback for failures. you can then pull your custom data from the response and display whatever messages you wish.